# How to run ray docker on M1?

Tags: python, docker, ray

Attempt to run ray docker image on M1 results in

```sh
$ docker run -p 10001:10001 -p 8265:8265 -p 33963:33963 rayproject/ray:latest
> WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested
```

I've tried to use `DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64`, but then nothing happens:

```sh
$ DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/amd64 docker run -p 10001:10001 -p 8265:8265 -p 33963:33963 rayproject/ray:latest
>
$ docker ps
> CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

The `latest` tag has digest `744f499644cc`

Comment: It's just a warning, so I'd expect it to run? As I understand it, M1 Macs can run amd64 code by emulating an x86 CPU.

Comment: For some reason it doesn't say anything more, neither does it start. So my assumption was that it just doesn't work. Do you happen to know how I can get more logs out of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image has `/bin/bash` defined as the command to run when it starts. When you run it, you don't attach a TTY, so the container exits immediately.

I'm not familiar with the image, so I don't know the way to run it correctly and your port mappings confuse me a bit. But a way to run it is

```
docker run -it rayproject/ray:latest
```

That will put you at a prompt inside the container and you can explore the contents.